# Lubuntu 16.04 No sound

Tags: sound

Hi I am new so be gentle. I am unable to get sound to work on my repurposed Lenovo Ideapad (Intel Atom)I have Lubuntu 16.04 Installed and have checked that nothing is muted. sound works on headphones. The laptop previously had Windows XP and sound worked fine.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Firstly I would suggest you try Lubuntu 18.04 LTS (from 2014-April, releases are *yy.mm* in format).  Lubuntu 16.04 had 3 years of supported life (5 years applies to main Ubuntu only as seen in https://lubuntu.me/xenial-released/).  Whilst the main Ubuntu part of your system will have near two years of support, your desktop, gui programs are already EOL which you should see if you enter `ubuntu-support-status` in a terminal (ie. lots of unsupported files).  The command `sudo lshw -C sound` will list-hardware of class=sound which can help us help you with sound)

Comment: I though would re-install Lubuntu 18.04 LTS and see if sound works there first, as why fix sound on an already mostly-EOL product?  (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/)  You can 'try lubuntu' before installing it to check to see if sound works on Lubuntu 18.04, but even if it didn't, I'd suggest you use it instead for security reasons alone.  *and note sorry 18.04 is from 2018-April in last comment*